# Jmeter: Need to display latency in Summay Report

Tags: jmeter

The Summary Report of Jmeter displays also all the data required to analyze the performance of web request. This includes

1. Labels
2. ## Samples
3. Average
4. Min
5. Max
6. Std Deviation
7. Error%
8. Throughput
9. KB/Sec
10. Avg. Bytes

It would be great if it were possible to display the latency as well in the same table. Is there a way to add this column to display latency in the Summary Report (I'm not talking about the file write component) in the GUI and have it saved to CSV file with the "Save Table Data" option in the Summary Report.

If not that, then is there any other Listener that would show all the data listed above along with Latency?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by simply uncommenting *(removing **#** sign)* the following property in **jmeter.properties** file

```
 #jmeter.save.saveservice.latency=true
```

JMeter properties file can be located in  `JMeterInstallation/bin/` directory.

Comment: This solution I believe is for writing the results to xml/CSV file. What I want to know is we can add a column "Latency" in the Jmeter GUI > Summary Report Listener, the way it is displayed in "View Results In Table" Listener.

Comment: You are right, this will add a latency column in the table (generated CSV file). I don't think there will be a straight-forward approach for adding a latency column in JMeter Listener GUI itself. For that purpose, may be you can look into to creating your own listener! https://jmeter.apache.org/extending/jmeter_tutorial.pdf